# Non classpath objects in heap dump

Tags: java, maven, jetty, guice, velocity

I've took a heap of my application in order to find out which objects get promoted to old generation. After some investigation I found out that there are tons of int[]. Below you can see path to GC roots of one of those int[]:

[image]

Theare are no guice or apache velocity libraries in classpath which I checked with mvn dependency:tree

I run my app with mvn jetty:run command

So, could you please tell me where are these objects are coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform your heap analysis outside of Maven.

Those classes are coming from Maven itself.

Comment: for what purpose Maven creates them?

Comment: for the normal processing of maven phases, goals, and plugins.